# Disabling syntax highlighting in a specific window in neovim

Tags: neovim

I'm having an issue with spell highlighting in my neovim configuration. I'd like spellchecking to be enabled and syntax highlighting to be off when I'm editing markdown and text files, and I can get it to work manually. However, when I try to automate this using `ftplugin`, the changes don't apply.

---

In my `init.vim`, I have

```
syntax on
```

Opening any file has intended behavior, syntax highlighting is on.

---

In `ftplugin/markdown.vim`, I have:

```
setlocal formatoptions=1
setlocal linebreak
setlocal spell spelllang=en
setlocal statusline+=\ w:%{WordCount()},
setlocal syntax=off
```

All other options apply as intended except for syntax options. I know this isn't an issue with spellchecking not working, as I can still see the `SpellBad` highlighting when setting manually.

---

Setting `setlocal syntax=off` manually works fine, I'm just stumped as to why it doesn't apply inside the `ftplugin`. Any ideas?

---

system information:

- nvim v0.4.3
- Zorin OS 16

Answer (score 0):

if its a `filetype plugin`, then everything you got in the `markdown.vim` should be applied `only to` the filetype `markdown`, right?

so try this:

```
set formatoptions=1
set linebreak
set spell spelllang=en
set statusline+=\ w:%{WordCount()},
set syntax=off
```

i am deducing from your situation (setlocal works manually, but not in ftplugin) that `setlocal` works only from within vim (as a command). makes sense?